# Unable to get Web API to work in my MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I get the following exception when i access the Web api route, but the site works fine otherwise.

I'm running MVC application that is still partially on web forms.  We're using structuremap for DI, and I followed the advice here (http://lucid-nonsense.co.uk/dependency-injection-web-api-and-mvc-4-rc/) to set up DI for WebAPI, but it made no difference.

What requires System.Data.Services 3.5.0?  It seems odd to me that this is 3.5 and not 4.x

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver
>   assembliesResolver) at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver
>   assembliesResolver) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.get_Cache() at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using RC or beta or nightly build?

Comment: I'm using RC. All packages up-to-date according to NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system missing .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 which comes with ADO.Net Data Services. You can try to install ADO.NET Data Services v1.5 CTP2: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23113 and see if it works. Even if gives error during installation it might work.
Which DB Context Generator are you using? If you using EF 4.x DbContext Generator then it might need older version of Data Services i think. EF 5 which comes with MVC4 don't work with VS2010.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I'm not near my workstation now, but fyi, another project in the same VS2010 solution works fine with the WebAPI - this project is the standard sample webapi project.  i didn't know there was an issue with VS2010 and MVC4/EF5.

Comment: The sample project don't use DbContext Generator, all code is done manually. My guess is you are using Ef 4.x DbContext Generator which look for ADO.Net Data Services.

If you look at EF 5.x DbContext Generator it says it would only work with "Visual Studio 2012 RC": http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d01a981-91b8-492c-b42c-c771c3f31e03
Microsoft want to force people to upgrade...